# how display html file from sdcard in android

Tags: android, html, android-sdcard

how i ll display html file in web view my html file is inside `sdcard("/Citations/DirectTaxLaws/1950/rtffiles/[1950]018ITR00812(All).rtf")`  i want to display it web view in android emulator... But I'm not able to display its showing some error, I have tried this code

```
WebView detailsLink = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
detailsLink.loadurl(" /Citations/DirectTaxLaws/1950/rtffiles/[1950]018ITR00812(All).rtf");
```

I'm not able to set path of sd card, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Please try this

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/index.html");
```

Comment: then what is "[1950]018ITR00812(All).rtf".

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
detailsLink.loadurl("file:///mnt/sdcard/Citations/DirectTaxLaws/1950/rtffiles/[1950]018ITR00812(All).rtf");
```

Comment: no its not working telling no file exist while i allredy put  instide mnt\sdcard directory

Comment: If you type the same url in the Android browser, does it works ?